# Access $_SESSION of specific server from other server

Tags: php, session, websocket, ratchet

I have a website, in which I use websocket- PHP Ratchet- using class `Chat`.
In my website, `$_SESSION['user_id']` is well defined. I wish to access this value in the `Chat` class.
How can I access this value in the websocket server, whilst this value resides in the website server?
When I do try to access it, I get error: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION` (the error line is highlighted in the code)

This is my `Chat.php`:

```
<?php
namespace dealspace_websocket;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
require_once __DIR__ . "/../Model/DBConnection.php";

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $JSonMsgObject = json_decode($msg, true);
        if($JSonMsgObject['type'] === 'updownvote') {
            $connection = new \DBConnection();
            $allowUpdate = false;
            try {
                $sql = 'SELECT `voters`
                        FROM `deals`
                        WHERE `id` = :id
                        LIMIT 1';
                $stmt = $connection->dbh->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    'id' => $JSonMsgObject['deal_data']['dealid']
                ));
                $allowUpdate = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($allowUpdate !== false) {
                    $votersString = $allowUpdate['voters'];
                    if($votersString !== '')
                        $votersArray = explode(',', $votersString);
                    $votersArray[] = $_SESSION['user_id']; // --- Here I try to access --- \\\
                    $votersString = implode(',', $votersArray);

                    $allowUpdate = false;
                    try {
                        $sql = 'UPDATE `deals`
                                SET `votes_counter` = :votes_counter, `voters` = :voters
                                WHERE `id` = :id';
                        $stmt = $connection->dbh->prepare($sql);
                        $allowUpdate = $stmt->execute(array(
                            'votes_counter' => $JSonMsgObject['deal_data']['votes'],
                            'voters' => $votersString,
                            'id' => $JSonMsgObject['deal_data']['dealid']
                        ));
                        if($allowUpdate === true) {
                            $deal_dataOBJ->dealid = $JSonMsgObject['deal_data']['dealid'];
                            $deal_dataOBJ->votes = $JSonMsgObject['deal_data']['votes'];
                            $returnMsg->type = 'updownvote';
                            $returnMsg->deal_data = $deal_dataOBJ;
                            foreach($this->clients as $client) {
                                $client->send(json_encode($returnMsg));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(\PDOException $e) {}
                } 
            } catch(\PDOException $e) {}
            $connection->disconnect();
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

My shell script of the server:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    use dealspace_websocket\Chat;

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

Comment: propaply it helps: http://socketo.me/docs/sessions

use session.cookie_domain

Comment: @db1975 I edited the question and attached my websocket server shell script. It's quite different from the attached websocket server shell script in the link you attached. The creation of the server is different between my code and the link's code. how can I attach the `$session` to my `$server` in my code?